# Bring up Color Palette

Tags: cocoa, color-picker

How can I create an action so when a button is clicked the Apple color palette window appears?  I do not want to use an `NSColorWell`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the color panel?  There's a method orderFrontColorPanel in the Application place holder in IB -- just connect that to your button.

Comment: You can also send it to the first responder.

Comment: @rodelmar i need to set the colour of button whatever we have selected through panel?